# Is there a rectangle with a maximum area which has two corners at the x axis, one corner at $y_1=e^x$ and one at $y_2=2e^{-x}$ .

Tags: calculus, derivatives, area

The inverses of $y_1$ and $y_2$ are :

$x_1=ln y$

and

$x_2=-ln\frac{y}{2}$

we need them to to calculate the side $a$ of a rectangle.

The area of a rectangle is defined as its one side multiplied by its other one.

$P=a*b$

$a=x_2-x_1$

$b=y$

$P=y*(-ln\frac{y}{2}-ln y)$

We derive $P$.

$P'> 0$

Is this method of solving that problem correct?

Comment: Same $x$? That's not a rectangle. Different $x$? By choosing them suitable negative, we can make the area arbitrarily large.

Comment: No. Same $y$. The calculation seems right. He also got that $P$ keeps increasing.

Comment: http://s14.postimg.org/3oz6u9wm9/20150908154722.jpg

Comment: @AndréNicolas I found what I think is a global maximum, but there is some disagreement about this.

Comment: There is some reason for different answers, the question is not precise.   Of course there is no global max.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for your reply, and I see what you mean now.  (I was making an assumption not stated in the problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{Note}$:  There is no global maximum for the problem as stated; 
in the solution below,

I am making the additional assumption  that the rectangle lies below both of the graphs.

---

You have the correct idea; $\;$simplifying $P$ gives

$P=y\big(-\ln\frac{y}{2}-\ln y\big)=y\big(-(\ln y-\ln 2)-\ln y\big)=y(\ln 2-2\ln y)$,

so $P^{\prime}(y)=y(-\frac{2}{y})+1\cdot(\ln 2-2\ln y)=\ln 2-2-2\ln y=0$ when

$\hspace{.3 in}\ln y=\frac{1}{2}\ln 2-1$ and $\displaystyle y=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{e}$.

Since $P^{\prime\prime}(y)<0$ when $\displaystyle y=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{e}$, this gives a maximum.

---

Alternatively, if we let $x$ be the x-coordinate of the left side of the rectangle, we get

$A=Bh=(\ln 2-2x)e^x,\;\;$ so $A^{\prime}(x)=e^x(\ln2-2-2x)=0$ when $x=\frac{1}{2}\ln2-1=\ln\sqrt{2}-1$

Comment: that is a local maximum, no global maximum exists.

Comment: $A=Bh=|\ln 2-2x| e^x$

Comment: @WW1 It is a global maximum, since the function is increasing to the left of the critical point and decreasing to the right.  (I did not use absolute values in the expression for the base, since $x<0$).

Comment: it only decreases up to $x=\frac 12 \ln 2$ at which point the absolute value makes it start increasing

Comment: @WW1 Maybe I'm wrong, but I think only negative values of x make sense in the problem -- If you look at the picture provided by the OP, $x_1<0$.

Comment: that's perhaps a bit tricky since what was graphed showed $e^{−x}$ instead of $2e^{−x}$ giving the impression that the problem is symmetric about the y axis.

Comment: @WW1  You were right, and I was wrong: this is not a global maximum for the problem as stated.  (I was assuming that the rectangle lies below the point of intersection of the graphs, but the problem doesn't specify this.)